# How can I collaborate with multiple developers in cloud9

Tags: cloud9-ide

I'm running cloud9 on a VPS. I have looked all over and I can't find how to invite multiple developers to collaborate on a project. Am I missing something or the open source version doesn't allow this capability and my only option is to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collaboration features are not available in the standalone version of Cloud9, because of high technical difficulties. It will be available in the free version of the hosted version tho.

Comment: Is this still the case?